# CMake: Check if file has too long lines

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to implement a check whether a certain text file contains lines over 130 characters. If so, the build should fail.

The code in CMakeLists.txt currently reads

```
# Define the text file to be validated
set(TEXT_FILE_PATH "... path to file ...")

# Add a custom command to fail the build if the validation output file is not empty
add_custom_command(
  TARGET ValidateTextFile
  COMMAND grep '.\{131\}' ${TEXT_FILE_PATH} && exit 1 || exit 0
  COMMENT "Failing build if validation check fails"
  VERBATIM
)

# Make sure the validation is performed before building the main target
add_dependencies(target_name ValidateTextFile)
```

Although the file contains one line that is too long, the build does not fail.

I think that if there is a line of at least 131 characters, then `grep` should return true and `exit 1` be run. Otherwise `exit 0` will be run.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a static analysis tool by the ways suggested by CMake to have such a check?

Comment: A **single quote** (`'`) is not a delimiter of the arguments in CMake. Your `grep` command takes the first parameter `'.\{131\}'` (verbatim!), so it attempts to find lines started with `'`. By building the project with `make VERBOSE=1` you may examine exact command lines which are launched.

Comment: @Friedrich. Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @Tsyvarev. Do you have a suggestion how I can write the command? Just removing `VERBATIM` didn't help.

Comment: Sure, this [blog post by kitware](https://www.kitware.com/static-checks-with-cmake-cdash-iwyu-clang-tidy-lwyu-cpplint-and-cppcheck/) would be a starting point. You would also have to configure cppcheck/clang-tidy/whatever to fail if lines are too long.

Comment: "Just removing VERBATIM didn't help." - Once again, the problem is not with VERBATIM, the problem is with **single quotes** which are not consumed by CMake and passed to the `grep` unmodified. Correct: `".\\{131\\}"` (Backslashes needs to be escaped because they are processed by CMake first.)

Comment: @Tsyvarev. Oh, I misinterpreted your comment "(verbatim!)" as it having to do with `VERBATIM`. Thanks for your clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add_custom_command(TARGET)` is used incorrectly in this case. Use [`add_custom_target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) instead.

Furthermore I'd recommend going with platform independent logic instead of relying on the presence of `grep`. You could e.g. use a cmake script file for this purpose:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(TEXT_FILE_PATH "test.txt")
set(MAX_LENGTH "130")

add_custom_target(ValidateTextFile
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -D "FILE=${TEXT_FILE_PATH}" -D "MAX_LENGTH=${MAX_LENGTH}" -P check_linelengths.cmake
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

**check_linelengths.cmake**

```
#[===[
 MAX_LENGTH the maximum line length
 FILE       the path to the file
#]===]

math(EXPR LENGTH_LIMIT "${MAX_LENGTH}+1")

file(STRINGS ${FILE} ERROR_LINE LENGTH_MINIMUM ${LENGTH_LIMIT} LIMIT_COUNT 1)

if (ERROR_LINE)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "A line was found in ${FILE} that exceeds the limit of ${MAX_LENGTH} chars: '${ERROR_LINE}'")
endif()
```

Comment: I managed to make this solution work. Using Yocto/BitBake, which I don't know by heart, made things just a little bit more complicated.